# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog when consuming service in .net

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am getting this error: **org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.** when consuming a goberment webservice, the thing is that everything was working fine until last friday.
the web service is

https://palena.sii.cl/DTEWS/CrSeed.jws?WSDL

and it returns a seed that needs to be signed. the strange thing is if you consume this service with a test program like .net webservice studio it throws the error, but if you consumes this service with http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html it works fine.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is an Windows Update (KB3147461). 2 solutions:

1. Uninstall it and try again.
2. Is it on Windows 10? Update you application to Framework 4.6.

Comment: thank thank thank you!!!!!!!!!!! i just update my app to framework 4.6, and yes i have win 10. problem solved

Comment: is there any other workaround? I'm deploying to Azure

Answer (score 0):

After installation of .net 4.6 or above version in server (deployment server). It fixed the issue. 
I spent around 4 days on this issue